# Soap Return String in PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I m trying to simply return String and Print it on Page.

Here PHP code

`$client = new SoapClient("path/track_on.asmx?WSDL");
$result = $client -> demoa("working!") -> demoaResult;`

print_r($result);

Soap Service

`[WebMethod]`

```
public string demoa(string emaildemo)
{

    string a = emaildemo;
    return a;

}
```

Error :

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$demoaResult in C:\xampp\htdocs\track_on\index.php on line 4($result = $client -> demoa("working!") -> demoaResult;)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$client = new SoapClient("path/track_on.asmx?WSDL"); 
$result = $client -> demoa("working!");

print_r($result->demoaResult);
```

You are trying to access the `demoaResult` variable in the `demoa` method, but you should access it from the `$result` variable

Comment: Can you access "path/track_on.asmx?WSDL" manualy in browser? Does it display the wsdl definitions? And if so... cand you run "var_dump($client->__getFunctions());" to see if demoa() is displayed?